# using mathematica plots in LaTeX

Tags: plot, import, wolfram-mathematica

I would like to use plots created with `Mathematica` inside my `LaTeX` environment. Is it possible to plot the `Mathematica` code completely inside the `LaTeX` environment?

If it is not possible, does anyone know a good way to implement the `Mathematica` plots inside my `.tex` file?

The simplest way is a simple `.png` export and `\includegraphics` but the resolution of the picture is not satisfying.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pagesize ,landscape, fontsize=5pt, fleqn]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=0.75cm,right=0.75cm, top=0.75cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage[svgnames,table,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\pagestyle{plain}
\setlength{\columnsep}{30pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}

torus

\[\text{parametric: } \vec{r}(u, v) = \begin{pmatrix}(c + a\cos(v))\cos(u) \\ (c + a\cos(v))\sin(u) \\ a\sin(v) \end{pmatrix} \hspace{5mm} u, v \in[0, 2\pi)\]
\[\text{implicit: }\left(c - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right)^2 + z^2 = a^2\]

%here should be the 3D plot.%

\end {multicols*}
\end{document}
```

And this would be the parametric plot created with `Mathematica`

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (2 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply save your Mathematica notebook as a Latex file. All the graphics will generate eps files. 
Then just add:

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

You'll be able to use pdflatex.

Here's a useful link:
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GenerateTeXWithTheWolframLanguage.html

Comment: Basically what I was looking for. Thanks Mary :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** AFAIK it is not possible to run *Mathematica* codes inside LaTeX.

**2.** Export the picture as PDF.

See the image below. You can do it easily with mouse.

[image]

Comment: Well my current solution is the export to a `.png`/`.pdf` and include it into my `.tex` file.

Comment: It would have been a more elegant way of using my plots:)

Comment: @montju, this is the single solution. Or you can try to plot using another tool: gnuplot, for example.

Comment: I already considered this solution - using a tool inside of `LaTeX`. But I think I will stick with the `.pdf` export solution for the moment. Easy and the results are good :)

Comment: Mathematica has a command line interface, so it is possible to do it from one go if you want to cheat.